# Perl file reference array in Search::Vectorspace

Tags: arrays, perl, vector, search-engine, text-mining

Trying to get the example code from [`Search::VectorSpace`](http://search.cpan.org/~mceglows/Search-VectorSpace-0.02/VectorSpace.pm) to work, and not getting the expected results. I am fairly new to this so please bear with me if this is trivial.

I constructed two txt files with content following:

boys.txt

```
aaron robbie james
```

girls.txt

```
jane marie betty
```

The code I am trying to get working correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Search::VectorSpace;

my @docs = ("/home/test_vector_search/girls.txt", "/home/test_vector_search/boys.txt");
my $engine = Search::VectorSpace->new( docs => \@docs);
$engine->build_index();

while ( my $query = <> ) {
    my %results = $engine->search( $query );
    print join "\n", keys %results;
}
```

Running it with a girl name (Jane) and a boy name (aaron) gives me:

```
Making word list:
Finished with word list
*jane*
/home/test_vector_search/boys.txt
/home/test_vector_search/girls.txt
*aaron*
/home/test_vector_search/boys.txt
/home/test_vector_search/girls.txt
```

So not quite what I expected!

Quote from Module

> Object constructor. Argument
>   hash must contain a key 'docs' whose value is a reference to an array
>   of documents. The hash can also contain an optional threshold setting,
>   between zero and one, to serve as a relevance cutoff for search
>   results.

I guess the problem lies with the reference array (`@docs`)?

Any help/insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Search::VectorSpace is expecting `@docs` to be the contents of `boys.txt` and `girls.txt`, try:

```
my @docs = ("aaron robbie james", "jane marie betty");
```

e.g.

```
echo -e "rob" | perl test-search.pl 
Making word list:
Finished with word list
aaron robbie james

echo -e "jane" | perl test-search.pl 
Making word list:
Finished with word list
jane marie betty
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, that works! Would it be complicated to construct a function that would take a list of files, and report best file match based on a search string with this piece of code?

Comment: Not really. You'd probably build a hash of, e.g. `"aaron robbie james" => "/../boys.txt"`, then use it to lookup the filename based on the result.

Comment: Could you point me to some info where I can see examples of how this might be done?